# NSPredicate evaluateWithObject: ?any object?

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

Does anyone know of any documentation that explains what exactly you can pass to `evaluateWithObject:(id)object`

Since it takes an (id), I take that to mean I can literally pass anything to it.

But if that's the case, how would you distinguish the difference between a failure due to an object it couldn't figure out how to validate vs. a failure that failed a successfully applied evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any object can be validated against any predicate, unless the object doesn't work with the operator being used.  If that happens, you'll get a runtime exception, so you'll know that you did something wrong.

**Example**

```
@import Foundation;
#import <objc/runtime.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"moo"];

    NSLog(@"%hhd", [p evaluateWithObject:@"moo"]);
    NSLog(@"%hhd", [p evaluateWithObject:@[]]);

    return 0;
}
```

*Compile with: `clang -framework Foundation -fobjc-arc  -fmodules test.m`*

*Run as: `./a.out`*

*Output:*

```
2015-11-23 08:35:42.927 a.out[91256:5691654] 1
2015-11-23 08:35:42.930 a.out[91256:5691654] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object (
).'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88e8ee32 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff872284fa objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007fff8e2ac62f -[NSMatchingPredicateOperator performPrimitiveOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 498
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8e212dd7 -[NSPredicateOperator performOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 286
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8e212b8d -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 313
    5   a.out                               0x0000000101a8decf main + 159
    6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff86c4c5ad start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
[1]    91256 abort      ./a.out
```